# Minimum Number of jumps need to reach end of an array in O(n) with constant space

Tags: arrays

Problem:
Given an array of integers where each element represents the max number of steps that can be made forward from that element. Write a function to return the minimum number of jumps to reach the end of the array (starting from the first element). If an element is 0, they cannot move through that element. If the end isn’t reachable, return -1.

Examples:

Input: arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 2, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9}
Output: 3 (1-> 3 -> 9 -> 9)
Explanation: Jump from 1st element
to 2nd element as there is only 1 step,
now there are three options 5, 8 or 9.
If 8 or 9 is chosen then the end node 9
can be reached. So 3 jumps are made.

I have solved the problem but i am getting time limit excceeded runtime error in geeks for geeks

Here's the code:

```
int jumps = 0;
    
if(arr.length <=1)
    return 0;
if(arr[0] == 0)
    return -1;
        
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ) 
{
    i += arr[i];
    jumps++;
}

return jumps;
```

Comment: I don't know what that algorithm is supposed to do, but ask yourself what happens if `arr[i]==0`

Comment: Please provide more info. Describe the goal. Provide restrictions and allowed assumptions on the input. Why do you think that a single counting can provide the minimum? I'd expect several attempts of counting different ways and then answering with the best one. Show a [mre] which demonstrates a run and the determination of a result. Take the [tour] and read [ask] please.

Comment: The "Minimum Number of jumps need to reach end of an array in O(n) with constant space" is too easy. Try for O(1) with `i=arr.length - 1;`. That is much better and does not conflict with the rules you provided here. (Kind of a joke. I want to illustrate how little info you provide.)

Comment: First of all, your algorithm doesn't fully solve the problem. Imagine an array `[2, 9, 1,1,1,1]`. The correct solution is 2, but your algorithm will return 4. Second, your algorithm goes into an endless loop if it hits a zero. For instance `[2,3,0,1]`

Comment: Or imagine an input of `[1, 0, 1]`. The correct anwser is -1, your algorithm will get caught in an endless loop (and therefore failing the test with a "time limit exceeded" error)